# How to use ruby to scrape a react website from a remote linux server?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, watir

I want to scrape a react website using the ruby watir gem on a remote linux server but keep getting the following error:

> /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:134:in
>   `path': can't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:45:in`
>   firefox'

Here is my code:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, headless: true
browser.goto("https://www.pinterest.com")
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861871/can-i-use-watir-to-scrape-data-from-a-website-on-a-linux-server-without-monitor/3863321) but the links either return 404 or are archived and the code deprecated.

I need to login, then get a new page and push buttons on that page to download a report file for a date range.

Answer (score 0):

> You'll get that error if Firefox isn't installed, or isn't accessible on your path. Reinstall if you already have it.

Source: [selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:134:in `path': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523308)

So, you might want to use Firecast, a reinstall might help. In case you have a different browser, you could test with Chrome for instance.

Some more things to look at:

1. You might also need to install the right webdriver. You can also use https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers
2. I have got the same error as you posted, then I ran `gem install webdrivers` and used it in the code, also I switched to chrome:

```
require 'watir'
require 'webdrivers'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
browser.goto("https://www.pinterest.com")
```

Finally, without webdrivers you get something like

> C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:136:in `binary_path': Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
>   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH.
>   More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.

and with all set up correctly you might get something like (most likely related to Chrome):

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57725/devtools/browser/34a42518-c3d9-4e14-af8e-9a137b11625b
>   [0808/012434.304:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The Content-Security-Policy directive 'prefetch-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled.
>   ", source: https://www.pinterest.com/ (0)
>   [0808/012437.286:INFO:CONSOLE(240)] "No signed in Google accounts available - visit accounts.google.com to ensure that at least one account is signed in, otherwise no data will be returned from this API.", source: [https://www.gstatic.com/*/mss/boq-identity/*/js/k=boq-identity.IdentityYoloWebModuleset.en_US.fUFh6X86RzU.es5.O/am=Aw/d=1/rs=AOaEmlH5BdY58S_qoulxSYv6tYMpThlVYw/m=yolo_frame_library](https://www.gstatic.com/_/mss/boq-identity/_/js/k=boq-identity.IdentityYoloWebModuleset.en_US.fUFh6X86RzU.es5.O/am=Aw/d=1/rs=AOaEmlH5BdY58S_qoulxSYv6tYMpThlVYw/m=yolo_frame_library) (240)

Comment: How would this work on a remote server where I can't be signed in to Google or install a browser?

Comment: Hmm, not with this gem, maybe using curl or using an http client to make the get requests you need.

Comment: e.g. curl -d 'username=myname&password=sEcReTwOrD123&csrf=123456' http://example.com/login, which is basically a post request to a login for of a website. (see here: https://tech.saigonist.com/b/code/how-login-any-website-using-curl-command-line-or-shell-script.html)